# How to replace the first letter out to a autonumbering from edit text

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to android / java.
I had that function fully functional on `windows CE` with `C#` so what it did in `C#` was putting the text into the `TextBox` when the user scaned a `cardnumber` with a barcode reader; then it tooked, for example, 3 pictures with the text `KD55` in the `TextBox`, and then saved the pictures with names like the following:

```
  1.0D55
  2.1D55
  3.2D55 and so on
```

and then he takes a new Y61 then it wil go like this

```
  1.0Y61
  2.1Y61
  3.2Y61 and so on
```

I hope anyone can help me out with this or translate it into Java / Android

```
  btn_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {              
              cameraimage();
                }
            });        
               jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                                 return;
                    }

String text = cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if(text.substring(0,1).equals("K"))
                    {
                        text = (i+1) + "." + i + text.substring(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text=(i+1) + "." + i + text ;//.substring(0));
                    }
                }
                String photofile = text + ".jpg";


                String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + photofile;
                    File picfile = new File(file_name);
                    try {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    } finally {

                    }
        refreshcamera();
                    refreshgallery(picfile);
    private void refreshgallery(File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

how i did it in C#

```
string str1 = this.textBoxCardNumber.Text.Substring(0, 1) == "K" ? this.textBoxCardNumber.Text.Substring(1) : this.textBoxCardNumber.Text;
    string str2 = (string) (object) Directory.GetFiles(this.picturesPath, "*" + str1 + ".JPG").Length + (object) str1;
            this.takenPictures.Add(this.picturesPath + str2 + ".JPG");
            this.Cam.SnapshotFile.Filename = str2;
```

Comment: want to remove 1st char?

Comment: yeah out to a autonumbering Wonder if it is possible with Count instead? as java doesn't support wildcards

Comment: this type of expected output, you can do with normal for loop

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it's works or not as per your need

Comment: what u mean by 100 in your for loop? if you need 100cards means , should store in array with all card names. then process with that array name

Comment: thats was just for a test but i am not sure if i understand you right i have to type in all the cardsnames? in the array

Comment: to give you are more clear look on what i am trying to do is that we have a card(that goes from A-Z-1-99999) that we are putting on some of our parts and then we scan it in with a barcode reader so we get the cardnumber(so we can name all the pictures that are taken after that card) and then we takes a couple pictures and then we move on to a new card and do the same and when we are done with that we uploading all the pictures to our sql so the name of the card is just a ID so all the pictures with that name goes into the right card

Comment: try with my code it's clearly shows what you want

Comment: now it saves it after i changed 100 out to 1 then they are called 1.0M79983 but can only take 1 pictures but if i do change 1 out to 3 then they are called 3.22.11.0M79983 and can also only take one picture i think is due to it just replace the picture as it doesn't giving a new name

Comment: as i can get it to take multiple pictures with using date SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ss"); Date now = new Date(); String photofile =formatter.format(now)+ text + ".jpg"; so i wonder if it might be a click counter on the btn_take_photo that resets on new text that could do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by using a click counter with help from Sathish

```
private int counter = 0;
btn_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                
                counter++;
                count.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                cameraimage();
            }
        });
             @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                String Counting = count.getText().toString().trim();
                String text = cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();
                {
                    if(text.substring(0,1).startsWith("K"))
                    {
                        text =  Counting+text.substring(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text=  Counting+text ;//.substring(0));
                    }
                }

                String photofile =text + ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. I assume 3 pictures (As per your question). so i put 3 in `for loop`

```
import java.io.*;

class StackOvr
{
    public static void main(String jsk[])
    {
        String str = "KD55";

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if(str.substring(0,1).equals("K"))
            {
                System.out.println( (i+1) + "." + i + str.substring(1));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( (i+1) + "." + i + str);//.substring(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is tested code by myself.

> Output

```
1.0D55
2.1D55
3.2D55
```

This may helps you.

Comment: would that just only Works for Card D55? or all cardnumbers as we have Cards that goes from A-Z  01-99999

Comment: you may need to extend your condition as per your need

Comment: is there anyway other way to do String str = "KD55"; so you can use `cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();` instead

Comment: you can use only cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim(); this way

Comment: how do i then use it in my `String text = cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();` instead of `String str = "KD55";` 

so it can be used on `String photofile = text + ".jpg";` to rename the pictures

Comment: get text from your EditText then remove K then concat with .jpg

Comment: thats on the right way i getting the output
0M79983
1M79983
2M79983
but it doesn't save it to the picture is still called KM79983

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117348/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-j-and-kewin-bjork-nielsen).

Comment: instead of System.out.println you need to put text = (i+1) + "." + i + text.substring(1); and in else part text=(i+1) + "." + i + text ;